# How to list processes using my current terminal for their stdout/stderr

Tags: bash, process, stdout

Sometimes I have processes which are not descendents of the shell I am using, but they still have my console open as their stdout or stderr (eg running `setsid yes &` will get me in this state). How do I get a list of all such processes?

Comment: `ps` without any arguments should give you the list current console session processes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lsof `tty`
```

This uses `tty(1)` to get your current `tty` device special file, and then passes that to `lsof(8)` to see which processes have that file open. I'm pretty sure anything taking `stdin` from your terminal, or outputting `stdout` or `stderr` to your terminal, must have your terminal device file open.